# my loop keeps looping also its looping the wrong thing?

Tags: eclipse, loops, while-loop, switch-statement, boolean

boolean test = true;// my loop starts here and i want to be able to loop the //switch statement when non of the cases are selected, I want the loop to go to back to case 1 after displaying the error message.

```
while (test)

Proceed = Next.nextInt();
switch (Proceed) {

    case 1:// Proceed 
        System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit pin below.");
        Scanner Pin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Pincode = Pin.nextInt();
        if (Pincode > 9999 && Pincode < 99999) {
            System.out.println("1)Display Balance");
            System.out.println("2)Withdraw Cash");
            System.out.println("3)Other services");

        } else {
         System.err
                    .println("Sorry,the pin you enterd was incorrect\nyour card is being ejected\nPlease wait...");
        }
        test=false;
        break;

    case 2:// Return Card
        System.err.println("Your card is being ejected.\n Please Wait..");
        test=false;
        break;

    default:  // i want to display this message and send it back to case 1. when i do the method i'm doing it just keeps spamming this message.
        System.err.println("Sorry your request could not be processed.Please re-try");
        test=true;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `proceed`?

Comment: Proceed = Next.nextInt();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it back to case 1 then you need to set proceed to 1. I'm guessing that Next.nextInt() will give you 1, 2 but then 3 and then 4, etc. And anything over 2 will go to the default case

Comment: Dont get it so i completely remove the loop and set proceed to 1 ?Proceed = Next.nextInt();

Comment: Try putting a debug statement so that you can see what proceed is being set to